Solving inequality induction for 2n+3 ≤ 2^n
I have a problem that asks to prove $2n+3 ≤ 2^n$ for $n > 3$. After doing the base case and IH, I take the following steps:

$2(k+1)+3 = 2k+3 +2 \leqslant 2^k +2$ (because of the IH)
$2^k + 2 \leqslant 2^{k+1} + 2$ (because $2^k+1 > 2^k$)
$2^k + 2 \leqslant 2^{k+1}$ (because for $k > 3, 2^{k+1} > 2^k+2$)
$2(k+1)+3 \leqslant 2^{k+1}$

Is it acceptable for me to make those claims on steps 2 and 3, or do I need to prove them?

For you help, you need to enclose $k+1$ in {} to make the whole thing the exponent, instead of using ()

It is better to say the reason for step 3 is $2^{k+1}-2^k=2^k>2$, which is more obvious.

Assuming your inductive hypothesis gives $n=k$, you should start from $2k+3\leq 2^{k}$ then multiply both sides by 2 to eventually get to the consequent (i.e. prove statement for $n=k+1$), instead of adding both sides by 2 to match the LHS.
This is because you essentially created an additional lemma you would need to prove on step 3; assuming you are not already given that $2^{n+1}>2^n +2$ if $n>3$.
Consider that definition of exponentiation requires multiplication; this means that you "have to" multiply both sides by 2 once to get from $2^k$ to $2^{k+1}$ axiomatically/per definition, which you did not utilize in your proof (thus your proof may be vague, depending on what lemma you have in your hands).

You can simply use $2\le 2^k$ for $k\ge 1$.
Therefore it is a one liner:
$2(k+1)+3 = 2k+3 +2 \le 2^k +2\le 2^k+2^k=2^{k+1}$
